# How to get element's status of response body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

There is a form which connected with expressJS.  When i press the submit button, form post input data(image direction) to a path and i am getting it with router.post() function.

When i send wrong image direction, the response of image status is 404.

Question is How can i get this status. I want to put it in a variable.

[image]

form code:

```
extends ../layouts/main-layout.pug
block content
    form(action='/admin/add-product', method='POST')
        .row
            .input-field.col.s6
                input#name.validate(name ='name',type='text', placeholder='Please Enter A Product Name')
            .input-field.col.s6
                input#name.validate(name='image',type='text', placeholder='Please Enter A Product Image')
            .input-field.col.s6
                input#name.validate(name='state',type='text', placeholder='Please Enter A Product State')
            .input-field.col.s6
                input#name.validate(name='price',type='text', placeholder='Please Enter A Product Price')
            .input-field.col.s12
                button.btn.waves-effect.waves-light(type='submit', name='submit')| Submit
```

router.get code :

```
module.exports.postAddProduct = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.name);
    res.redirect('/');
};
```

Comment: Post the code!!!

Comment: i have posted it

Answer (score 0):

Console the response and access it like `console.log(res.status);`

Comment: i have already tried it. But it also gives 200 code. I want to get status code of image like above image.